# What is "Torque Break"?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, torque

I am looking at the specifications for thread lockers, and henkel/loctite specify "Torque break" and "Torque prevail" in in./lb. as shown in the link below:

http://www.na.henkel-adhesives.com/industrial/product-search-1554.htm?nodeid=8797951950849&msdsLanguage=EN_US&selectedTab=technical

I had expected to see the torque required to break the "lock", and to continue turning in in.⋅lb. (or N⋅m) as described on wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-locking_fluid

What does this "Torque break" value mean, and how is it calculated?

Comment: Why would you trust wikipedia here? Henkel makes the stuff...

Comment: @solar-mike My point was regarding the units they use - not the values provided. I have always measured torque in N⋅m or ft.⋅lbs., so am trying to determine what their "inches per pound" unit equates to.

Comment: I would guess that's an error on the data sheet "in/lb" should be "in-lb". Try contacting the company if you need to verify.

Comment: indeed here is a data sheet with the same number and correct units: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjLvJbRxNXZAhUip1kKHZYxCdYQFggvMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwebaps.ellsworth.com%2Fedl%2FActions%2FGetLibraryFile.aspx%3Fdocument%3D13437%26language%3Den&usg=AOvVaw1UExaiwbW3yyX-hN08_Hvz

Comment: As already suggested, it's probably just a typo or mistake. The correct unit is in*lb.

Comment: @agentp Thanks! I did fill out their contact form but haven't heard back. Looks like it was just a typo - which kind of invalidates my question; should I delete it?

Comment: Well, I’m deleting ny answer as it is not popular ...